# what binding options are availiable in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, binding

It's worth mentioning that when setting up a binding programmatically, it's worth checking an equivalent binding in IB and making sure you're passing all the same settings to the programmatic binding. For instance, I see in IB that the "Allow Editing Multiple Values Selection", "Conditionally Sets Editable", and "Raises For Not Applicable Keys" options are all checked by default for an NSTextView's Attributed String binding. That would mean our programmatic binding should probably really look like:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First Name", @"Address", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"vivek kumar", @"Vivek Bhavan", nil];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects 
                                                       forKeys:keys];

[textview bind: NSAttributedStringBinding 
      toObject: obj 
   withKeyPath: @"text" 
       options: dictionary];
```

Can we bind a value using NSDictionary in options ? After we will get a value using functions. Or It may used for updating data in TextField through Core Database

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation tells you what bindings are available for a given view, and what options are available for a specific binding. [This is the relevant page for the `NSTextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTextView.html), and this is the *options* table found on that page for the `NSAttributedString` binding.

[image]

As far as I'm aware you can't specify custom keys for this dictionary - instead you are limited to those documented under the **'Binding option column'**. Similarly there is no leeway in the `type` of the *value* associated with each key - this is defined by Apple, and is found in the corresponding **'Value class'** column.